# How to explode a string ignoring the case of the delimiter?

Tags: php, string, explode, case-insensitive

I have the following code:

```
$string = "zero Or one OR two or three";
print_r(explode("or", $string));
```

Right now this results in:

```
Array ( [0] => zero Or one OR two [1] => three )
```

But I want to ignore the case of the delimiter so it works with `Or`, `OR`, ... and that my result is:

```
Array ( [0] => zero [1] => one [2] => two [3] => three )
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$string = "zero Or one OR two or three";
$keywords = preg_split("/or/i", $string);
echo '<pre>';print_r($keywords);echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => zero 
    [1] =>  one 
    [2] =>  two 
    [3] =>  three
)
```